# Adding validation to text field from bootstrap or angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In the following form even though have added the attribute `required`  do not see the validation done from bootstrap. Is there a way to add validation either from angularjs or bootstrap.The required field should turn the text box red if no values are entered in it.How to go about this

```
<form name="schoolform" class="add-school-form" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row row-no-padding">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <input  class="form-control" id="rsummary" name="rsummary" type="text" value="" placeholder="Related Summary" ng-model="rsummary" required>
                    </div>        
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <a class="btn pull-right" ng-click="create()">Create</a> 
           </div>
        </div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Edit1:

```
<div class="row row-no-padding" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : schoolform.summary.$invalid && !schoolform.summary.$pristine }">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 vz_input">
                        <input  class="form-control" id="summary" name="summary" type="text" value="" placeholder="Summary" ng-model="project.summary" data-fv-field="summary" required jira-type="input"  data-type="str">
                        <p ng-show="schoolform.summary.$invalid && !schoolform.summary.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
                    </div>        
                </div>
 <a class="btn pull-right" ng-click="create(schoolform.$valid)">Create Ticket</a> 




$scope.create = function (isValid)
{
        alert(isValid);
        if (isValid) { 
            alert(isValid);//false
        }
        else{
            //process the form
        }
}
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15734695/3016654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test.html

```
           <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : schoolform.summary.$invalid || schoolform.summary.$pristine }">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 vz_input">
                    <input  class="form-control" id="summary" name="summary" type="text"   placeholder="Summary" ng-model="project.summary" data-fv-field="summary" required >
                    <p ng-show="schoolform.summary.$invalid || schoolform.summary.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
                </div>        
            </div>
          Form validation:  {{schoolform.$valid}}
      <a class="btn pull-right" ng-click="create(schoolform.$valid)">Create Ticket</a> 

</form>
```

test.js

```
$scope.create = function (isValid){
    console.log(isValid);
    if (isValid) { 
        alert(isValid);//false
    }
    else{
        //process the form
    }
}
```

or 
     test.html

```
           <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : (schoolform.summary.$invalid && !schoolform.summary.$pristine) || invalid }">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 vz_input">
                    <input  class="form-control" id="summary" name="summary" type="text"   placeholder="Summary" ng-model="project.summary" data-fv-field="summary" required >
                    <p ng-show="(schoolform.summary.$invalid && !schoolform.summary.$pristine) || invalid" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
                </div>        
            </div>
          Form validation:  {{schoolform.$valid}}
      <a class="btn pull-right" ng-click="create(schoolform.$valid)">Create Ticket</a> 

</form>
```

test.js

```
$scope.create = function (isValid){
    console.log(isValid);
    if (isValid) { 
        alert(isValid);//false
    }
    else{
        $scope.invalid = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

validation is already there.Just put this CSS class so you will get an idea.

```
.add-school-form input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
    background-color: red;
  }

  .add-school-form input.ng-valid.ng-touched {
    background-color: green;
  }
```

This will trurn the text-box background color red if use put cursor in it and left it blanks otherwise it will green.

EDIT CODE :

```
<form name="schoolform" class="add-school-form" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row row-no-padding">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <input  class="form-control" ng-class="{'red':schoolform.$submitted && schoolform.rsummary.$error.required }" id="rsummary" name="rsummary" type="text" value="" placeholder="Related Summary" ng-model="rsummary" required>
                    </div>        
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn pull-right" ng-click="create()" value="Create"> 
           </div>
        </div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS :

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
  }


  .green {
    background-color: green;
  }
```

you need submit action for this. So link is changed to submit button

Also you can place your create() call on form tag like this one.

```
<form ng-submit="create()">
```

So,it will take care of both form submission and clicking action.

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CbH7dcrG7Z4D0ErtuL76?p=preview)

EDIT NEW .

There is **$valid** and **$invalid** flag associated with each form.
For your form either you can pass **schoolform.$valid** or **schoolform.$invalid** whatever you prefer to your create function like this
**create(schoolform.$valid)**.

If form is valid then **schoolform.$valid =true,schoolform.$invalid=false** and if it is invalid  then **schoolform.$valid =false,schoolform.$invalid=true**

And move the create function to form tag

Here the updated HTML .

```
<form name="schoolform" ng-submit="create(schoolform.$valid)" class="add-school-form" novalidate>
   <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row row-no-padding">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <input  class="form-control" ng-class="{'red':schoolform.$submitted && schoolform.rsummary.$error.required }" id="rsummary" name="rsummary" type="text" value="" placeholder="Related Summary" ng-model="rsummary" required>
                    </div>        
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn pull-right"   value="Create"> 
           </div>
        </div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS :

```
$scope.create = function (boolIsFormValid) {
    console.log(boolIsFormValid)
 };
```

Here is the updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mxpBehWtvsP4Pca1SU46?p=preview)

Comment: Its also work for this if you want to validate data without submitting the form

Comment: Pls tell me ,how will create() know if the form is valid or not

Comment: :) please tick in front of my answer if it is helpful