# AngularJS form validation issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-validation, angularjs-forms

I am trying to do a simple form validation using angular js. But it doesnt seems to work and I am not getting what I am missing.

HTML

```html
<form role="form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" name="registerForm">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" type="text"
                                        autofocus="" required ng-class="{'has-error': registerForm.firstname.$invalid}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" type="text" value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" type="email" value="" ng-class="{'has-error': registerForm.email.$dirty}">
                                <div ng-show="registerForm.email.$dirty">Email Invalid</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Organization Name" name="organizationName" type="text" value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select data-ng-options="item.Display for item in OrganizationTypes track by item.Value" data-ng-model="SelectOrganizationType" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">-Select Organization Type-</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                           
                            <input type="button" value="Register" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" data-ng-click="Submit()" name="btnSubmit"/>
                           
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

Now the issue is, I am expecting that if I start entering invalid email then it will show me error message "Email Invalid". But that doesn't happen.

Also when i put a debug before submitting blank form, it says "registerForm.$valid = true"

Any guess what am I missing. Any module that i need to include ?

Here is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JYcMlo62pduLJrHq55SL)

Comment: Please check :http://stackoverflow.com/a/31118444/1638718

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding validation to text field from bootstrap or angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115604/adding-validation-to-text-field-from-bootstrap-or-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a bunch of stuff. First of all, you need to have your fields associated with a model for them to be validated. Second, your syntax for accessing errors is incorrect.

[**Here is a working plunkr for what you are trying to do.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/eChfFnjWUrBHtNVZrVS5)

This is the relevant code:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form role="form" name="registerForm" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" ng-model="firstname" type="text" autofocus="" ng-class="{'has-error': registerForm.firstname.$error.required}" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" ng-model="lastname" type="text" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" ng-model="email" type="email" value="" ng-class="{'has-error': registerForm.email.$error.pattern}" ng-pattern="/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/i" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" ng-model="password" type="password" value="" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Organization Name" name="organizationName" ng-model="organizationName" type="text" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select data-ng-options="item.Display for item in OrganizationTypes track by item.Value" data-ng-model="SelectOrganizationType" class="form-control">
          <option value="">-Select Organization Type-</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <input type="button" value="Register" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" data-ng-click="Submit()" name="btnSubmit" />

    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <div ng-show="registerForm.firstname.$error.required">You must enter a first name.</div>
  <div ng-show="registerForm.email.$error.pattern || registerForm.email.$error.required">Email Invalid</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, weird that we have to bind it to ng-model to make validation work.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need `registerForm.email.$error.email` to trigger the 'invalid email' alert.

Second, I guess you have to bind these input fields with `ng-model`s, but I am not sure if this is necessary.

One more thing, add 'novalidate' to the form element.

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" type="email" value="" ng-model="" >
      <div ng-show="registerForm.email.$error.email">Email Invalid</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: We have to bind input fields with no-model.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I am not sure but I think you also have to use **$error** with **$dirty** like this:

```
<div ng-show="registerForm.email.$dirty && registerForm.email.$error.email">Email Invalid</div>
```

Also, add **novalidate** to disable default browser validation like this:

```
<form role="form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" name="registerForm" novalidate>
```

Comment: this is all true whether it alone solves the issue or not, only checking for $dirty will show as soon as you touch the input

Comment: @Sumit, can you create a plunker?